# Java Collections ArrayList index value verification

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

`<table>` with `<td>` inside it having multiple span values. Refer to the html code:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td class="country"> <span data-bind="text:Name">USA</span>
    ( <span data-bind="text:RowCounts">7</span>
    )</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="country"> <span data-bind="text:Name">Japan</span>
    ( <span data-bind="text:RowCounts">4</span>
    )</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="country"> <span data-bind="text:Name">S. Korea</span>
    ( <span data-bind="text:RowCounts">2</span>
    )</td>
</tr>
```

We want to scrape and store the country and row count value. After that will verify the count (i.e specific country and row count)

**Java**

```
ArrayList < String > countryCount = renewalSelectionProcessInPortfolio();
WebElement tblPortfolio = cpi.tblMangePortfolio;
List < WebElement > allRows = tblcountry.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (int row = 1; row <= allRows.size(); row++) {
  String countryDetails = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblcountry']/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[1]")).getText();
  countryCount.add(countryDetails)
}
```

The above stores all the values(country name and count) in an single index like: `USA (7) Japan (4) S.Korea (2)`

After that we want to verify that some specific country count, such as `Japan`. So in the above situation, how can we verify the count when it's stored in single index and not able to get the exact country and count value.

please provide suggestion

Comment: guys waiting for the response

Answer (score -1):

Why not try to store you values in a hashtable? The country becomes the index and the count becomes the value... Then just look up the country and retreive your value.